# Align react-native-svg into View component

Tags: css, react-native, svg, alignment, react-native-svg

View style:

```
export const ImageView = styled.View({
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  backgroundColor: 'red',
});
```

import svg file:

```
import MyImage from '../../assets/myImage.svg';
```

Render usage:

```
<ImageView>
  <MyImage width={330} height={225} />
</ImageView>
```

The render result is not centered:

[image]

Comment: You haven't added flex property.

Comment: as @AnujSharma said use flex:1 or try to use alignSelf: 'center' for the image style

Comment: it worked. Do you wanna create a awnser?